# Identifying the entity in sentiment analysis using Lingpipe

Tags: nlp, machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

I have implemented sentiment analysis using the sentiment analysis module of Lingpipe. I know that they use a Dynamic LR model for this. It just tells me if the test string is a positive sentiment or negative sentiment. What ideas could I use to determine the object for which the sentiment has been expressed?

If the text is categorized as positive sentiment, I would like to get the object for which the sentiment has been expressed - this could be a movie name, product name or others.

Answer (score 4):

Although this question is really old but I would like to answer it for others' benefit.

What you want here is concept level sentiment analysis. For a very basic version, I would recommend following these steps:

1. Apply sentence splitter. You can either use Lingpipe's Sentence Splitter or the OpenNLP Sentence Detector.
2. Apply part-of-spech tagging. Again you can either use Lingpipe's POS tagger or OpenNLP POS Tagger.
3. You then need to identify tokens(s) identified as '*Nouns*' by the POS tagger. These token(s) have the potential of being the targeted entity in the sentence.
4. Then you need to find sentiment words in the sentence. The easiest way to do this is by using a dictionary of sentiment bearing words. You can find many such dictionaries online.
5. The next step will be find out dependency relations in sentences. This can be achieved by using the [Stanford Dependency Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml). For example, if you try out the sentence - "*This phone is good.*" in their [online demo](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp), you can see the following 'Typed Dependencies':

   det(phone-2, This-1), 
   **nsubj(good-4, phone-2)**, 
   cop(good-4, is-3), 
   root(ROOT-0, good-4)

   The dependency **nsubj(good-4, phone-2)** here indicates that **phone** is the *nominal subject* of the token **good**, implying that the word **good** is expressed for **phone**. I am sure that your sentiment dictionary will contain the word **good** and **phone** would have been identified as a *noun* by the POS tagger. Thus, you can conclude that the sentiment **good** was expressed for the entity **phone**.

This was a very basic example. You can go a step further and create rules around the dependency relations to extract more complex sentiment-entity pairs. You can also assign scores to your sentiment terms and come up with a total score for the sentence depending upon the number of occurrences of sentiment words in that sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Usually sentiment sentence means that the main entity of such sentence is the object of that sentiment. So basic heuristic is to NER and get first object. Otherwise you should use deep parsing NLP toolkits and write some rules to link sentiment to object.