# Can NLTK be used to Analyse the sentiment a certain word has within a sentence?

Tags: nlp, nltk

I have a quick question and could not find the answer anywhere on the internet:

Can NLTK be used to Analyze the sentiment a certain word has within a sentence?

Like: Sentiment for iPhone: "Even though it is terrible weather outside, my iPhone makes me feel good again." = Sentiment: positive

Comment: What's the sentiment of 'iPhone' here: "My iPhone makes me feel really good. Yeah, I mean it. Honest. Actually it's a load of rubbish."

Comment: Ofcourse NLTK cannot pick up sarcasm ... but my question is still unanswered :(

Comment: There are plenty of online sources (e.g., on google scholar) on using the NLTK for sentiment analysis. Are you asking for something more? Will targeting a certain NP really improve performance?

Comment: @alexis well yes. looking at: "Even though it is terrible weather outside, my iPhone makes me feel good again." under normal circumstances a NLP would say terrible vs good = to slightly negative! But I am asking if, with NLTK, I can Specify a keyword for which the sentiment is analyse (e.g. iPhone)

Comment: I understand your example, but still I was wondering if it's really something that needs fixing. Answer below.

Comment: The idea that the sentiment of a particular utterance could be detected with any reasonable accuracy is far from true. The value of sentiment analysis comes when you have a large enough collection of utterances that you can find a trend in the data. If enough of the input sentences are simple enough, it is easy to see that iPhone gets a positive sentiment signal even though the analysis of individual utterances is sometimes severely flawed.

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought of breaking down the text into clauses ("it is terrible weather outside", "my iphone makes me feel good again"), and evaluating them separately? You can use the NLTK's parsers for that. This will reduce the amount of text you have to analyze, though, so it might end up doing more harm than good.

This won't help you in cases like "Microsoft Surface is no iPad, it's terrible" (where your target is "iPad"), since the sentiment is negative but the iPad wins the comparison. So perhaps you'll also want to check the syntactic analysis, and only examine sentences where your target word is the subject or object. Whether these will give you better performance is anybody's guess, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have much experience with NLTK but I have done some concept level sentiment analysis using NLP libraries in Java. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594244/identifying-the-entity-in-sentiment-analysis-using-lingpipe/12100778#12100778) is how I did it. The same approach should work for you if you are able to identify dependencies in NLTK. This approach works fine for simple rules but may not work well for complicated sentences.